# disconnected callback in aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning

disconnectedCallback() in LWC fires when a component is removed from the DOM. Does we have similar function in aura component which fires when a component is removed from the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Aura, You have a concept called [Unrender Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm)

The base unrender() function deletes all the DOM nodes rendered by a component’s render() function. **It is called by the framework when a component is being destroyed**. Customize this behavior by overriding unrender() in your component’s renderer. This method can be useful when you are working with third-party libraries that are not native to the framework.

You generally want to extend default unrendering by calling superUnrender() from your unrender() function before you add your custom code.

This code outlines a custom unrender() function.

```
unrender: function () {
    this.superUnrender();
    // do custom unrendering here
}
```